# Writing a javascript method in controller or some other place and calling it from Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

for some reason whatever helper functions that I am writing , they are not working in my Handlebars, saying that they are not helper functions. I want two things:

1. Is there anyway I can write functions in controller and call them easily from the Ember? If yes can you please give me example or link or some help how can I do it?
2. Can I assign variables etc in ember each loops, like if I can declare a variable in outer each loop and assign it in the inner each loop and then use that assigned value after the inner loop finishes
3. For some reason, my ifCond helper is not working, it says that ifCond is not a helper, is there any builtin if for comparing two values and return true or false in ember, like two different string etc

Any help please - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Basically no. You should a getter/computed property for this.

So if you have this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  get foo() {
    return 10 + 50;
  }
}
```

you can write `{{this.foo}}` it will show `60`.

For classic class you would do this:

```
Component.extend({
  foo: compute(function() {
    return 10 + 50;
  }),
})
```

### 2 No. If you want to do business logic do it in a computed property or getter in the components `js` file.

So if you want a list of values and the sum for example, build a getter (or a computed property for classic style) producing this total and then use it in the template.

Try to keep most of your logik in the `js` file.

### 3: use `ember-truth-helpers`

Most people use [`ember-truth-helpers`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers). It has an `eq` helper which allows you to do `{{#if (eq this.foo "something")}}`.